# Java Calendar not giving end of hour

Tags: java, calendar

Based on Epoch seconds, I convert it to the start of hour and end of hour.

```
    long epochSeconds = 1589374800L;
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSeconds);
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")));
    now.setTimeInMillis(instant.toEpochMilli());

    System.out.println(now.getTime()); // Correct --> Wed May 13 06:00:00 PDT 2020

    Calendar endOfHour = (Calendar)now.clone();
    endOfHour.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    endOfHour.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    endOfHour.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);

    System.out.println(endOfHour.getTime()); // Wrong ---> Wed May 13 06:29:59 PDT 2020
```

The start of hour seems correct, but the end of hour is not giving it right, instead of upto 59 minute, 59 second, 999 millisecond it is giving only half hour difference.

Comment: You’re overcompicating things by mixing modern data-time classes ( `Instant`, `ZoneId`) with the poorly designed and outmoded ones (`Calendar`, `TimeZone`). I recommend you avoid the latter completely and stick to the modern and superior ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing `java.time` and `java.util.Calendar` types. Don't do that. For one thing, you're losing the `TimeZone` you specified when you clone. Basically, `Calendar` is a **mess**. But you don't need it here, something like

```
long epochSeconds = 1589374800L;
LocalDateTime date = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSeconds) //
        .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")) //
        .toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println(date);
LocalDateTime endOfHour = date.withMinute(59) //
        .withSecond(59) //
        .with(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 999);
System.out.println(endOfHour);
```

Should meet your needs. Here that outputs

```
2020-05-13T18:30
2020-05-13T18:59:59.999
```

Comment: Good answer. A detail: `Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSeconds)` is even better (as in the question).

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks. Don't know why I went to millis. Force of habit.

Comment: I like the answer, and thanks for the details. However I would need to use `Calendar` today as there is dependency involved on code throughout. Any way to convert LocalDateTime to Calendar?

Comment: Far better to remove all of the `Calendar`(s). It really is that bad. For one thing, a `Calendar` has no concept of timezone (it stores everything as a 64-bit `long` offset in milliseconds from January 1 1970 at midnight UTC). And [of course there is](https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/java-8-date-time-api/to-date-conversion.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Small correction of your last comment. `java.util.Calendar` has a concept of timezones but `java.util.Date` not. Probably a typo.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Right you are. Mixing `Date`, `Calendar`, `LocalDateTime`, `Instant` and seconds epoch to milliseconds flusters me. I think it flusters everyone. Which is why it's such a **bad idea**.

Answer (score 2):

Two points (and one more at the end):

1. Just repeating what has already been said: don’t mix old and modern date-time classes. Use the modern ones exclusively. Forget about the old ones. They were always poorly designed anyway.
2. **Your observed result is correct and as should be expected.**

You are using Asia/Kolkata time zone for your (outmoded) `Calendar` object. Asia/Kolkata time zone is special in that it is not offset a whole number of hours from UTC as most time zones are, but +05:30, five and a half hours. Let’s look at your times in this time zone first. Your epoch second value (AKA Unix timestamp) is equal to 2020-05-13T18:30:00+05:30 in Asia/Kolkata. The end of that hour in Asia/Kolkata is 2020-05-13T18:59:59.999. This is the result that you get.

It seems that you are running your program on a JVM in a different time zone (perhaps America/Vancouver or America/Los_Angeles). This time zone is offset a whole number of hours from UTC, so 18:59:59.999 in India equals 06:29:59 PDT (your time zone).

**Half-open:**
I promised you a third point. Represent the end of the hour as the whole hour, here 19:00 rather than 18:59:59 and some number of 9s. The philosophical argument: The hour doesn’t end one millisecond before the next hour begins, so this is incorrect. The practical argument: It frees you from deciding how many 9s you need. java.time has nanosecond precision, so is able to represent nearly a million points in time between your end of the hour and the beginning of the next hour. You risk hitting such a point and assigning it to the wrong hour. In comparisons just make sure that you are checking whether a point in time is *strictly* before the whole hour where the hour ends.

**If you do need `Calendar` objects** for a legacy API:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");

    long epochSeconds = 1589374800L;
    ZonedDateTime now = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSeconds).atZone(zone);
    Calendar nowAsOldfashionedCalendar = GregorianCalendar.from(now);

    ZonedDateTime endOfHour
            = now.plusHours(1).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS).minusNanos(1);
    Calendar endOfHourAsOldfashionedCalendar = GregorianCalendar.from(endOfHour);
```

I included `.minusNanos(1)` to get the last nanosecond of the previous hour, but as I said, you should prefer to omit it if you can. The conversion to `GregorianCalendar` will truncate to milliseconds and give you the same result as in your code in the question.

Comment: Very good answer. Thank you so much! I wish SO allowed me to select two accepted answer.

Comment: Since you need to pass `Calendar` on, I have added the code for the conversion at the bottom of my answer. @NoviceUser. I’m absolutely fine with you accepting Elliot’s answer, as I said, it’s a good one.